# Match two Arrays as Object of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays and I need to make it as object of array

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
var arr2 = [a,b,c]
```

Is there any possibility to change the array to this format[a,{1,2,3,4,5}],[b,{1,2,3,4,5}],[c,{1,2,3,4,5}]

Could someone help me?

Comment: `[a,{1,2,3,4,5}],[b,{1,2,3,4,5}],[c,{1,2,3,4,5}] ` <-- what's this?

Comment: Probably OP means: `{"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[1,2,3,4,5],"c":[1,2,3,4,5]}`

Comment: Or this : `[[a,{1,2,3,4,5}],[b,{1,2,3,4,5}],[c,{1,2,3,4,5}]]` ??

Comment: @Jry9972 OP mentions: *to make it as object of array*

Comment: @Dmitri Pavlutin Oh ok!

Comment: ya make it as object of array. i dont know that term how to say

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan Create an object with properties name from `arr2` and values as an array `arr1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you need a object like this
{"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[1,2,3,4,5],"c":[1,2,3,4,5]}

So you can do it like this.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
var arr2 = ["a","b","c"];
var result={}
arr2.map(function(k){
result[k]=arr1;
})
console.log(result);
```

But here I am giving values of keys as arr1 reference so if arr1 will change value of keys in result will also change.

Comment: `map()` is not the best option. `forEach()` is more appropriate.

Comment: `map()` is used to transform an array to another (what you don't need to do). `forEach()` just to iterate the items, like you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = ['a','b','c'];

var result = arr2.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  obj[item] = arr1.slice(); // or = arr1 to keep the reference
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result); // {"a":[1,2,3,4,5],"b":[1,2,3,4,5],"c":[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

You have 2 cases:

- To create clones of the array use `result[item] = arr1.slice();`
- To keep the reference to the same array use `result[item] = arr1;`

Check more about the `reduce()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility to change the array to this
>   formate[a,{1,2,3,4,5}],[b,{1,2,3,4,5}],[c,{1,2,3,4,5}]

This is neither an array format nor a valid JSON literal, so this format could only be a string.

Assuming that you are looking for a string in the format you have specified

```
var output = "[" + arr2.map(function(value){return value+",{" + arr1.join(",") + "}"}).join("],[") + "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach to iterate through List and get your desired result.

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = ['a','b','c'];

var result = {} // Result: Object of Array

arr2.forEach(function(val, index) {
    result[val] = arr1;
})
```

I hope this is easy to understand :)